# Lazy loading grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I want to create a grid in knockout, but I don't know how to do pagination with lazy loading.

I have explored a [JSfiddle-KnockoutJS Grid](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QSRBR/) example, but there is no Total Records and Number of Pages in it.

My grid pagination part should be generated dynamically based on `pagesize` and `number of records` for particullar query.

I want to fetch records from database using `data table`.

If is there any control for KnockoutJS grid then please suggest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the Total Records and Number of pages of the simpleGrid like this:

```
Number of pages: <span data-bind="text: gridViewModel.maxPageIndex() +1"></span>
Total items: <span data-bind="text: gridViewModel.data().length"></span>
```

See the [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hWwbL/)